# How to implement Push To Talk in Voice+Fusion?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

As described in the title, I need a reliable way to control the ability to block the outgoing audio stream.

I didn't find how to do this, so I quickly implemented a RPC message that disables / enables the desired sound source for other players .. but this does not affect the audio stream.

But user needs a guarantee that his audio will not be transmitted anywhere until he turns on the appropriate in-game indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photon Voice and fusion require a Recorder to record the sound.
Then, no need to cut the sound over network , just disable its record locally (will also prevent delay)

```
public Recorder myRecorder; 
 
void OnKeyPressed()
{
    myRecorder.RecordingEnabled = true;
}
void OnKeyReleased()
{
    myRecorder.RecordingEnabled = false;
}
```

Something like that